# почему условный оператор в питоне себя не так ведёт

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

Я новичок и мне очень хотелось бы разобраться. Почему условный оператор в Питоне ведет себя не должным образом. Я создаю функцию, которая принимает один параметр. И если он меньше 5, то функция должна возвратить None, а если больше, то само это число. Когда я задаю аргумент этой функции меньше 5, например 3, то все в порядке, функция возвращает None, как и положено. Но, когда аргумент функции я ввожу больше 5, например 8, то в консоли вижу вывод и 8, и None. Почему так происходит?

```
def xxx(n):
    if n < 5:
        return None
    else:
        print(n)

y = 8
variable = xxx(y)
print(variable)
```

Out: 8
None

Comment: потому что функция xxx ничего не возвращает при n >= 5, поэтому `внутренний print(n) выводит 8, а внешний print(variable) печатает None`. Короче, результат работы функции xxx всегда None )

Comment: по умолчанию функция возвращает нон. добавьте после принта в функции       return True и результат изменится.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Объяснение

Любая функция python неявно возвращает `None`, если в функции не происходит `return`, т.е. даже если вы не пишите `return`, то функция вернет `None` - по умолчанию.

---

## Разбор кода

### Объявление функции

#### Случай первый

Вы вводите в функцию число меньше, чем `5`.

В таком случае работает первая часть условного оператора:

```
if n < 5:
    return None
```

и в результате работы функции выходит `None` (тот, что вы написали)

---

#### Случай второй

На вход подаётся число большее или равное `5`.
В таком случае работает вторая часть условного оператора:

```
else:
    print(n)
```

она печатает в консоль введённое значение, и возвращает None (неявно)

---

### Остальной код

После объявления функции следует код, где:

- вы объявляете входное значение, как число `8`,

```
y = 8
```

- вызываете функцию, и записываете её результат,

```
variable = xxx(y)
```

- после чего, вы выводите этот результат

```
print(variable)
```

В первом случае работы функции всё тривиально, функция выводит *ваш* `None`, а потом этот результат сохраняется в `variable` и печатается.

Если же происходит второй случай, тогда в консоль выводится входное значение, в коде - `8`, а также результат работы функции записывается в `variable`, т.к. мы ничего не вернули, то результат - стандартный `None`.
После чего вы также печатаете этот результат, и получается два вывода - сначала `print` в функции, а потом вне её.

---

## Мои предложения

Во втором случае, вместо вывода в консоль, верните результат:
т.е.

```
print(n)
```

замените на

```
return n
```

---

В первом случае выводите ответ в консоль из функции и не сохраняйте результат выполнения функции:

```
...
return None

y = 8
variable = xxx(y)
print(variable)
```

замените на

```
...
print(None)

y = 8
xxx(y)
```

---

## Ремарки

Советую воспринимать объявление функции, таким образом:

```
def some_func(some_inputs):
    # some code
```

превращается в

```
def some_func(some_inputs):
    # some code
    return None
```

(т.к. если в функции python сталкивается с `return`, он выходит из функции и не выполняет код, который может быть написан после первого `return`)

Если ваш `return` будет происходить раньше, то вы не наткнётесь на стандартный вывод

---

Можете поиграться со стандартным выводом, например:

```
def func():
    pass

print(func())  # None
```

(функция выполнится, и вернёт стандартный `None`)

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы возвратить число,  нужно его возвратить, а не напечатать

```
def xxx(n):
    if n < 5:
        return None
    else:
        return n
```

Comment: коротко и ясно.

Comment: @entithat, будь вы новичком, какой ответ вам помог бы разобраться лучше? На одной чаше весов очень подробный, отвечающий на большинство вопросов ответ, на другой - тот, что почти не отвечает ни на какие вопросы. Большинство склоняется к первому. И я солидарен с этим мнением.

Comment: @0dminnimda, Не знаю кому как, но мне иногда легче понять алгоритм по его поведению, нежели читать огромный кусок текста.